# How do I work on a form without checking it out of the Team Server?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

In SourceSafe I could "get the latest version" and work on my PC without checking the webform out. When finished I could double-check if anyone worked on it and then decide whether to check it in or not.

In Visual Studio 2008 Team Server, whenever I start working on a form it checks it out automatically. How do I work on a form without checking it out ? Were do I find the setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Environment ->

1. **Editing** combobox - set to *Do nothing*
2. **Allow checked-in items to be edited** - check this checkbox

Answer (score 3):

Why would you want this behavior?  Wouldn't it be best for your team to know that you are actively working on a page as to avoid concurrency issues?  More to the question, you could just right click the file in the filesystem and remove the 'read-only' checkbox in the properties.